# debug not working in PhpStorm

Tags: debug, phpstorm

I've got a fresh PhpStorm 6.0.3 installation on my machine.
Unfortunately when I create a project and place an index.html
in it, select that file and click on the debug icon, Chrome
is launched but instead of rendering my local html file it
simply displays some unrelated google page from the web,
(in my case the page https://www.google.it/?gws_rd=cr&ei=aouLUrjzDKe24ASq5IGACw
whose URL I do not recognize; the page just displays the google search window).
My index.html file is just a simple hello world file.

How can I solve this problem in PhpStorm? Is there something I need to configure somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: If you've not done configuration, then you might need to finish setting up your environment. Make sure you've configured PhpStorm so that it knows how to launch and debug PHP with your local webserver, Make sure you tell it how local files map to a URL so it knows what URL to load to fetch your index.html, and make sure you configure a browser so it knows what to launch to load the URL (it looks like Chrome is the default).

Comment: 1. what does your run configuration look like?
2. did you install the JetBrains IDE Support extension for Chrome? Do you see the message 'Waiting for connection from JetBrains IDE Support extension for Chrome' in Debugger tool window?